# The basic property of scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a scheme and $x$ is a point in $X$. Then there exists an open affine subscheme of $X$ named $SpecA$ such that $x\in SpecA$. I want to know 
  if $\overline{\{x\}} \subseteq SpecA $?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If a scheme $S$ is irreducible, then there exists a point $x \in S$ such that $\overline{\{x\}} = S$, so if the scheme is not affine, your property cannot hold. For example, consider a projective space $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ over a field $k$, and let $\mathbb{A}_k^n = Spec\, k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ be a piece of its standard cover. Then the point of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ that correspond to a prime ideal $(0) \in Spec\, k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ has this property.

Comment: It could also be described as the point of $\operatorname{Proj} k[t_0, \ldots, t_n]$ corresponding to the homogeneous prime ideal $(0)$.

Comment: I got it .Thank you very much.